# How to configure Nginx on an existing AWS server after reinstall

Tags: wordpress, nginx, configuration, nginx-config, reinstall

I reinstalled nginx after trying to install certbot.  I purged the existing data without making a backup and I am having trouble figuring out where the existing Wordpress database is.

**How do i reconfigure Nginx to point back to the rest of the wordpress files.  What location are they stored in?**

I tried just labelling it wordpress; tried linking it to other file locations i found using file transfer protocal.

I tried looking up where these are stored online.  I also tried making a new EC2 instance to copy but i cant find NGINX as an available format anymore.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.